# How to launch several cherrypy process?

Tags: cherrypy

The goal is to launch 4 cherrypy process (to make use of a 4 cores CPU) to handle 6 different web sites each with their own url.

Could you please give an example of how this could be accomplished ?

Comment: Hi Robert, do you really need this using CherryPy only? If you want to run multiple websites, I would go with a webserver (Nginx) and CherryPy behind it.

Comment: Hi i could use nginx. So if i just create all websites each in their own directory with their own regular cherrypy config and have nginx direct traffic on a first request first served basis, it will create an independent process with its own threads for each site right ?